# html2canvas объединить два блока в один

Tags: javascript, изображения, canvas, html2canvas

взял два канваса из двух разных блоков, как мне их обьединить и получить одну картинку?

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector(".block-system")).then(canvas => {
   canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas1');
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
html2canvas(document.querySelector(".finfo")).then(canvas => {
   canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas2');
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нарисуйте содержимое обоих `canvas` на третьем:

```js
let c1 = canvas1.getContext("2d")
c1.fillStyle='steelblue'
c1.fillRect(15,15,20,20);

let c2 = canvas2.getContext("2d")
c2.fillStyle='brown'
c2.fillRect(5,5,60,40);

let canvas3 = document.createElement("canvas")
document.body.append(canvas3)
canvas3.width = Math.max(+canvas1.width, +canvas2.width);
canvas3.height = +canvas1.height + +canvas2.height;
let ctx = canvas3.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0)
ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, canvas1.height)
```

```css
canvas {
  background: wheat
}
```

```html
<canvas height=50 width=50 id=canvas1></canvas>
<canvas height=50 width=70 id=canvas2></canvas>
```